# Normal operator implies $||Tv|| = ||T*v||$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I am trying to understand the proof in Sheldon Axler's textbook that $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is a normal operator if and only if $||Tv|| = ||T^* v||$ for all $v \in V$  I have included his proof below, but I then have questions on it.

> (Axler's proof) Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. We will prove both directions of this result at the same time. Note that
> \begin{align*}
> \text{$T$ is normal } & \iff T^* T - TT^* = 0 \\
> & \iff \langle (T^* T - TT^*)v, v  \rangle = 0 \text{ for all $v \in V$} \\
> & \iff \langle T^* T v, v \rangle = \langle TT^* v, v \rangle \text{ for all $v \in V$} \\
> & \iff ||Tv||^2 = |T^* v|^2 \text{ for all $v \in V$} 
> \end{align*}
> where we used 7.16 to establish the second equivalence (note that the operator $T^* T - TT^*$ is self-adjoint). The equivalence of the first and last conditions above give the desired result.

The first line follows from the definition of normal: $T^{*} T = TT^{*}$, so rearranging gives $T^{*} T = TT^{\star} = 0$. For the next result, Axler cites a theorem which states:

> Suppose $T$ is a self-adjoint operator on $V$ such that $\langle Tv, v \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$. Then $T = 0$.

There are two things I do not understand here. First, I do not understand why $T^{*} T - TT^{*}$ is self-adjoint and cannot figure out how to prove it. Second, it seems that Axler is using the result in reverse. 7.16 establishes one direction, that if an operator is self-adjoint and $\langle Tv, v \rangle = 0$, then $T = 0$. But he asserts that the result holds in both directions, beginning with the statement that the operator is $0$. Is the converse also true? (If so, does anyone have any tips on how to prove it?)

The next step follows from linearity in the first entry and rearranging. The final step, I believe, uses the definition of adjoint and the fact that $(T^*)^* = T$.

Help on understanding this proof would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$(AB)^{*}=B^{*}A^{*}$ for any two bounded operators $A$ and $B$. Also $T^{**}=T$ Hence $(T^{*}T-TT^{*})^{*}=T^{*}T^{**}-T^{**}T^{*}=T^{*}T-TT^{*}$ provin that $T^{*}T-TT^{*}$ is self-adjoint.

If it is already  proved that $ \langle Tv, v \rangle=0$ for all $v$ and $T$ self-adjoint implies $T=0$ then  what is your second question? Isn't it obvious $T=0$ implies $ \langle Tv, v \rangle=0$ for all $v$?

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The forward direction is immediate, since $\langle 0v,v\rangle=0$ for all $v$.

The sum of self-adjoint operators is self-adjoint, and each of $TT^*$ and $T^*T$ is self-adjoint.

The last step uses the fundamental property $\langle Tv,w\rangle=\langle v,T^*w\rangle$.